# Seeking a Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, patterns-and-practices

First off, I totally understand that an interface cannot contain a static method because what would the method act on - that is clear. Suppose I want an interface to mandate a method that is particular to a class but acts statically (and as an interface method may be shared by many classes.)

To propose a crazy example: let's say I have various cookers (Pressure Cooker, Wok, Microwave, Oil Fryer, Grill, Air Fryer and so on...) and I want them all to implement a Cook method to which I will pass ingredients so the method itself could be static and thus does not use any of the properties of the class. If I actually make this method static then there is no contract that I can use to constrain all these Cookers. If I create an interface with an instance method called Cook then I wonder how I could call it.

Does it make sense to create this interface? How do I call this method when I do not have an instance? Could I create a static instance of each implementing class (like Wok.Default or Wok.Empty) and use it to call the method when I only have ingredients and no instance? In this method I could decide whether I have a valid instance and either act on that instance or use passed ingredients.

Is this crazy? Is there a better way? Is there a pattern that applies to this? I've considered various patterns like Proxy, Facade, Adapter, and Decorator but nothing seems to exactly fit. The Mediator also seems close because I suspect it would be useful to have a 'intercept' in between that could identify the class thru a parameter but I am trying to not couple the method to an 'intercept' unless absolutely necessary. I am open to suggestion.

Comment: Why do you want this? Are you attempting to enforce purity/immutability?

Comment: I am attempting to enforce a contract. Any class implementing the interface would have to implement the method. But the method could be called statically without using the properties of the class. If I didn't use an interface how would I enforce that a class implement that method? But if I use an interface how would I call the method?

Comment: That's an implementation detail, not an effect.

Comment: Don't understand that comment. Do interfaces represent contracts?

Comment: FWIW Java 8 and later supports syntax called [static methods in interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html#static)

Comment: Thank you so much for that information. I am not familiar with that language and I will read about it. I have spent a great deal of time tackling this issue with many different implementations (none of which are trivial enough to post the code.)  As I said I have considered various patterns. I thought that here I could post a general question about design and not a specific question about how one would write a piece of code. That is why I kept language out of the post and asked specifically about patterns.

Comment: I would also love to see a reference that explains why interfaces are implementation details and not effects. I have searched my self in vain for such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many have said

> Static methods do not have access to instance data. They can’t access non static fields that are part of an objects state.

This is absolutely true but is causes many people to make this assumption:

> Methods that don’t use non static fields should be static.

This is not true because it ignores that there is another reason a method should be non-static: non-static methods can be dynamically dispatched. That is, they can be polymorphic.

Thus, a method that doesn’t use non static instance data can still have a good reason to be non-static.

This means that this code:

```
PressureCooker.Cook()
```

and this code:

```
new PressureCooker().Cook();
```

can accomplish exactly the same thing. However, supporting the second one allows this to work as well:

```
cooker.Cook();
```

The difference with this third one is that it doesn’t know that cooker is a PressureCooker. That’s decided elsewhere.

Now cooker can have a type that must have a Cook method but what kind of implementation (Wok, Microwave, Oil Fryer, Grill, Air Fryer) is also decided elsewhere.

So this lets you enforce an interface just fine. The type system ensures that whatever kind of cooker you’re given it will have a cook method.

As a bonus, you don’t even have to know if the method uses non static fields. That was also decided elsewhere.

In fact, since nothing is being passed to Cook() and nothing is being returned the only thing being decided here is *do it now*.

It’s very powerful to be able push details away and focus on just one thing. It makes your code robust because there are few things that impact it when they change. This lets those other things be dealt with elsewhere.

Comment: So this was exactly my conclusion! The polymorphic aspect of the call was a big point in favor of implementing an interface - along with the contract enforcement that an interface guarantees. However you kind of skimmed around one of my questions by using the fluent syntax of new PressureCooker().Cook(); So, specifically, does it seem reasonable to make the Cook() call with a static singleton? (In my language, C#, I don't see another way.)

Comment: @TerrierJack: Why do you need this to be `static`?

Comment: You mean the singleton or the method. As in the post above my first implementation of the method was static because "it did not use non-static fields" but I want to enforce a contract with an interface so the method is in every participating class without having to tell my fellow coders "write this static method!"

Comment: @TerrierJack: You're telling me *what* but not *why.*  You wanted the method to be `static`, but this answer explains why you probably shouldn't, so now you've moved your `static` to the instance. Why do you need this to be `static` at all?   As someone (clumsily) mentioned before, these are all just *implementation details.*  How does `static` help you here?

Comment: @TerrierJack: See also: [What is the X Y Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: If you mean the method then it comes down to calling it without a specific instance. I will admit that my example might be a little lacking (my actual problem has many classes and several possible interfaces) but imagine you and your neighbor both have a 'Skillet' but the 'Cook' procedure for a "Pork Chop" is exactly the same for both skillets. If I just want to cook a "Pork Chop" without specifying a specific 'Skillet' then how do I do it?

Comment: @TerrierJack cooker.Cook(porkChop);

Comment: I appreciate the X Y Problem point but sometimes your problem space is too specific to show. The actual problem I suspect is not all that unique but to explain the problem space here - heck, I'd have to write a book and it would obscure the questions. Is it acceptable to make a call to an instance method using a singleton? (Probably I should have just asked that.)

Comment: And is there a pattern that can remove the need to make that call with a singleton?

Comment: All instance methods call stacks lead back to something static. Ultimately `main()`. So yes it’s acceptable.